# Equivalent form of $\frac{\text{sgn}(x)}{|x|}$

Tags: absolute-value

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) that any real number $x$ can be written as $|x| = \text{sgn}(x)x$ where $\text{sgn}(x)$ is the sign function. Rearranging, this means that $\frac{\text{sgn}(x)}{|x|} = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$.

On the other hand, [WolframAlpha says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sgn%28x%29%2F%7Cx%7C) that $\frac{\text{sgn}(x)}{|x|} = \frac{1}{x^*}$ where $x^*$ is the conjugate of $x$ and that $\frac{\text{sgn}(x)}{|x|}$ is only equal to $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$.

Is this an inconsistency? Why does WolframAlpha omit the $x<0$ case?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says for $x>0$, $\dfrac{\text{sgn}(x)}{|x|}=\dfrac1x$; but Wolfram Alpha does not say *only* for $x>0$ is that true

Comment: Alpha considers complex $x$. For real $x$ we have $x = x^{\ast}$, so that's in agreement with wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That WA is talking about conjugates should be a clear hint that you are thinking about $x$ as a real number and WA is working with complex $x$.  If you give WA the hint that $x$ is real, it give you what you expect:  [WA: sgn(x)/|x| for x in reals](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sgn%28x%29%2F%7Cx%7C+for+x+in+reals)